# Hive terminal hangs on inserting data using INSERT command

Tags: hadoop, terminal, hive, insert, freeze

I am trying to insert data in an external hive table in Hive 1.2  from another table using INSERT COmmand-

```
INSERT INTO perf_tech_security_detail_extn_fltr partition 
            (created_date) 
SELECT seq_num, 
       action, 
       sde_timestamp, 
       instrmnt_id, 
       dm_lstupddt, 
       grnfthr_ind, 
       grnfthr_tl_dt, 
       grnfthr_frm_dt, 
       ftc_chge_rsn, 
       Substring (sde_timestamp, 0, 10) 
FROM   tech_security_detail_extn_fltr 
WHERE  Substring (sde_timestamp, 0, 10) = '2018-05-02';
```

But the hive shell hangs on-

```
hive> SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
hive> set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
hive> set hive.enforce.bucketing=true;
hive> INSERT INTO PERF_TECH_SECURITY_DETAIL_EXTN_FLTR partition (created_date) select seq_num, action, sde_timestamp, instrmnt_id, dm_lstupddt, grnfthr_ind, grnfthr_tl_dt, grnfthr_frm_dt, ftc_chge_rsn, substring (sde_timestamp,0,10) from TECH_SECURITY_DETAIL_EXTN_FLTR where substring (sde_timestamp,0,10)='2018-05-02';
Query ID = tcs_20180503215950_585152fd-ecdc-4296-85fc-d464fef44e68
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 100
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
```

Hive logs are as below-

> 18-05-03 21:28:01,703 INFO  [main]: log.PerfLogger
>   (PerfLogger.java:PerfLogEnd(148)) -  2018-05-03 21:28:01,716
>   ERROR [main]: mr.ExecDriver (ExecDriver.java:execute(400)) - yarn
>   2018-05-03 21:28:01,758 INFO  [main]: client.RMProxy
>   (RMProxy.java:createRMProxy(98)) - Connecting to ResourceManager at
>   /0.0.0.0:8032 2018-05-03 21:28:01,903 INFO  [main]:
>   fs.FSStatsPublisher (FSStatsPublisher.java:init(49)) - created :
>   hdfs://localhost:9000/datanode/nifi_data/perf_tech_security_detail_extn_fltr/.hive-staging_hive_2018-05-03_21-27-59_433_5606951945441160381-1/-ext-10001 2018-05-03 21:28:01,960 INFO  [main]: client.RMProxy
>   (RMProxy.java:createRMProxy(98)) - Connecting to ResourceManager at
>   /0.0.0.0:8032 2018-05-03 21:28:01,965 INFO  [main]: exec.Utilities
>   (Utilities.java:getBaseWork(389)) - PLAN PATH =
>   hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/hive/tcs/576b0aa3-059d-4fb2-bed8-c975781a5fce/hive_2018-05-03_21-27-59_433_5606951945441160381-1/-mr-10003/303a392c-2383-41ed-bc9d-78d37ae49f39/map.xml
>   2018-05-03 21:28:01,967 INFO  [main]: exec.Utilities
>   (Utilities.java:getBaseWork(389)) - PLAN PATH =
>   hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/hive/tcs/576b0aa3-059d-4fb2-bed8-c975781a5fce/hive_2018-05-03_21-27-59_433_5606951945441160381-1/-mr-10003/303a392c-2383-41ed-bc9d-78d37ae49f39/reduce.xml
>   2018-05-03 21:28:22,009 INFO  [main]: ipc.Client
>   (Client.java:handleConnectionTimeout(832)) - Retrying connect to
>   server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); maxRetries=45
>   2018-05-03 21:28:42,027 INFO  [main]: ipc.Client
>   (Client.java:handleConnectionTimeout(832)) - Retrying connect to
>   server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 1 time(s); maxRetries=45
>   ..........................................................

I have also tried to insert data normally in unpartitioned table but even that is not working-

```
INSERT INTO emp values (1 ,'ROB')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you have not written table before table name, like this below:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE emp
VALUES (1 ,'ROB'), (2 ,'Shailesh');
```

Write proper commands to make them work

Answer (score 0):

Resolved

MapReduce is not running due to wrong framename,so edited property mapreduce.framework.name in mapred-site.xml

Answer (score 0):

In a cluster environment, the property yarn.resourcemanager.hostname is key to avoid this problem. It worked great for me.

Use this command to monitor YARN performance:

`yarn application -list` and `yarn node -list`